# Scrolling divs at different speeds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create the effect seen in the header of http://anagram.paris/work/burgerking where the text moves as you scroll down.

I'm trying to do it with css margins and jQuery, but it doesn't seem to act right. I am using flex to vertically center all the content so I think that may be affecting it too.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var offset = 175,
scroll_top_duration = 1500,

// bind with the button link
$animation = $('.spacer');

$(window).scroll(function(){
if( $(this).scrollTop() > offset ) {
   $animation.addClass('stretch');
}
else
{
    $animation.removeClass('stretch');
}
});
```

css

```
.flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}
.spacer.stretch { padding-top: 4%; }

.spacer {
  position: relative;
  transition: padding .35s 0s ease; 
}
```

html

```
<div class="jumbotron indx-jumbotron flex">
<div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">

        <h1 class="spacer">Hi, I'm <strong>Lucas</strong></h1>
        <p class="spacer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>
        <div class="spacer">Button</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is simple parallax effect

At first, margin is not a good property to do that (performance issue) better is transform: translate3D(0px,0px,0px) ->  translate3D(0px,-100px,0px)

If you want to, I can write more, how translate3D works.

But if you want to ready to use solution look at here
http://scrollmagic.io/

If you want to now more about performance
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/

Comment: Thanks for the resource, lots of neat things. What I want I think is fairly simple and only use it on small areas. I was hoping to hard code it into the site rather thank link it in.

Answer (score 0):

I had to pretty much overhall the code, but this works properly.  To adjust the speed simply adjust the multiplier from `.5` to whatever you want.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".container .foreground").css({
      top:$(".container").height()/2-$(this).scrollTop()*.5
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container .background {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}

.container .foreground {
  position:absolute;
  font-size:40px;
  color:yellow;
  z-index:1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.spacer {
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="background" src="http://neil.computer/s/1.jpg" />
  <div class="foreground">
    Testing text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="spacer">

</div>
```

Comment: This looks great, but as I mentioned I want to add this effect to each element of the content (h1, p, etc) as it shows in the site I listed. Can your code do that?